# C# search Query Issue: Unable to Filter Posts Based on Title Keywords in Random Order

Tags: c#

If the user enters in the search bar a phrase example "Error chat" I want the query to find me all the Posts that have in the title the two words "error" and "chat" also in random order, I have tried filtering this way, but I always get back all the items, not taking into account this filter, the other filters however work correctly, I can't understand why.

```
public async Task<ListaPostDTO> RecuperaPostStudente(string userId, FiltroListaPostStudenteDTO filtro)
{
    try
    {
        List<Post> elencoPost = new List<Post>();

        string[] includes = { "IDCorsoNavigation", "IDStudenteNavigation", "IDStatoPostNavigation", "CommentoPost" };
        string[]? dividiRange = filtro.DataRange != null && filtro.DataRange != "" ? filtro.DataRange.Split("-") : null;

        List<string> titoloDiviso = filtro.Titolo != null ? filtro.Titolo.Split(" ").ToList() : new List<string>();

        Expression<Func<Post, bool>> query = (p => p.IDStudenteNavigation.UserId == userId
                && (filtro.IDCorso == null || p.IDCorso == filtro.IDCorso)
                && (filtro.NomeCorso == null || p.IDCorsoNavigation!.Nome!.ToLower().Contains(filtro.NomeCorso.ToLower()))
                //&& (filtro.Titolo == null || p.Titolo!.ToLower().Contains(filtro.Titolo.ToLower()))
                && (filtro.Titolo == null || titoloDiviso.All(t => p.Titolo!.ToLower().Contains(t.ToLower())))
                && (filtro.Descrizione == null || p.Descrizione!.ToLower().Contains(filtro.Descrizione.ToLower()))
                && (filtro.Data == null || p.Data!.Value.Date == DateTime.Parse(filtro.Data).Date)
                && ((filtro.OrderBy != "Data" || dividiRange == null) || (p.Data!.Value.Date >= DateTime.Parse(dividiRange[0]).Date && p.Data!.Value.Date <= DateTime.Parse(dividiRange[1]).Date))
                && (filtro.IDStatoPost == null || p.IDStatoPost == filtro.IDStatoPost)
            );

        elencoPost = (List<Post>)await _ifThenElseUnitOfWork.PostRepository.GetTable(query,
                pageSize: filtro.PageSize,
                pageNumber: filtro.PageNumber,
                orderBy: filtro.OrderBy,
                orderCrescente: filtro.OrderCrescente,
                includeProperties: includes);

        ListaPostDTO listaPost = new ListaPostDTO();
        listaPost.ListaPost = _mapper.Map<List<PostDTO>>(elencoPost);

        listaPost.NumeroPagine = await _ifThenElseUnitOfWork.PostRepository.PageTable(filtro.PageSize, query);

        return listaPost;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: I think we need a bit more info here. Like what does the _ifThenElseUnitOfWork look like, what example Titles do you have. What classes are important/what do they look like.

Comment: The most important thing to know for us are some example titles

Comment: But for the moment everything seems to be in place correctly. Like I only have 2 and a half theories here: 
0.5: The commented line is making trouble (I really dont think that this it)
1: Something isnt right with filtro.Titolo (also doubt it)
2: Something in your GetTable method is troublesome (also unlikely)
From the current knowledge weve been given theese are the only things that come to my mind. But im also very sure that you already looked into theese things